# winsock2 getpeername() function parameters detail

Tags: c++, winsock2

i want to know about the details of parameters for getpeername() function to get the IP Address of the connected client at server side.
i m working on dev c++,my code is working well about communication b/w client and server app.
thank you.

Comment: [The Microsoft Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/aa904962) have the answers you seek. And the arguments are the same as for the POSIX `getpeername` as well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That is not a particularly useful MSDN link.  In any case, the actual documentation for `getpeername()` on MSDN is here: [`getpeername()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738533.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's very useful as a starting point for those who don't know about it.

Comment: now i am able to find ip address using getpeername() but it always show 142.0.0.0, alas my client's ip address is 192.168.0.100 (client and server are on local network)